# ESP32 littlefs, change block size

Tags: esp32

Is it possible to change the block size of littlefs on ESP32?

In esp_littlefs.c you'll find: #define CONFIG_LITTLEFS_BLOCK_SIZE 4096 /* ESP32 can only operate at 4kb */

I don't understant why it cannot be set smaller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The limit arises from the 4 KiB erase block size of the SPI flash used on the ESP32 modules. Of course there is nothing preventing you from designing a filesystem with block sizes smaller than the medium's erase block size. But that would conflict with some design goals of filesystems like LittleFS (lightweight and wear-leveling-aware).